# ubuntu: "tomcat6 is not installed" after installing from synaptic

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, tomcat6

I am working with Ubuntu 11.
I installed tomcat6 via Synaptic package manager and used it within Netbeans 7.0.1.

It worked OK yesterday. 
Today , when I tried to deploy via Netbeans, I got a message:

> Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set
>   the correct username and password with the "manager" role in the
>   Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager. See the server log for
>   details.

So I added the following line to tomcat-users.xml:

`<user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager"/>`

then I did `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart` and got:

`* tomcat6 is not installed`

Huh?

Answer (score 3):

I would try `sudo apt-get purge tomcat6` and then try `sudo apt-get install tomcat6`

See what happens when you try to purge.

Also, with Ubuntu 11, you can simply type `sudo service tomcat6 restart`

Comment: I purged & installed. At the end of the install I get `* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat6, action "start" failed.`

Comment: be careful, but http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1707889 suggests: `sudo apt-get purge tomcat6 authbind ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao java-common libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcommons-collections-java libcommons-dbcp-java  libcommons-pool-java libcups2 libecj-java libjpeg62 liblcms1 libnspr4-0d libnss3-1d libservlet2.5-java libtomcat6-java openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib tomcat6 tomcat6-common tzdata-java`

Comment: so I purged again,reinstalled via synaptic and now everything is back to normal. But I still don't understand what happened here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell what happened either. Glad it's working again! Be sure to mark the answer as solved. Thanks

Comment: The "be careful" command above seemed to help for me. I made the mistake of manually deleting `/etc/solr`, `/etc/tomcat`, `/usr/share/solr`, and `/usr/share/tomcat`.