# Cannot start solr on Drupal based site

Tags: php, drupal, solr

I am trying to get a `php` / `Drupal` based website.  The site also uses `solr`, something which I've never used before.  I inherited this site and the documentation I was left says that I may need to restart `solr` which can be done by running:

`sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart`

I can see from my `Drupal` admin that `solr` isn't running so I tried running it.  I unexpectedly got a message saying `sudo: tomcat6: command not found`.  However when I list the directory `tomcat6` is clearly there.

These are the permissions:

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  7929 Mar 16  2012 tomcat6`

Does anyone know what the problem with this is and how I can resolve it?

This apparently was always working and I haven't installed anything since I started with this linux machine (VM).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should run it this way `./tomcat6 start`, if you want to run it directly using `tomcat6 start` you should add the script's directory path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I tried that and got the same message:

`john@john-VirtualBox:/etc/init.d$ sudo ./tomcat6 start
[sudo] password for john: 
 * tomcat6 is not installed
john@john-VirtualBox:/etc/init.d$`

Comment: It's not the same messages now you're getting `tomcat6 is not installed` in the output, it's probably an install problem check this [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678069/ubuntu-tomcat6-is-not-installed-after-installing-from-synaptic) it may help you

Comment: Yes you're correct, sorry.  I'll check out that link, thank you :)